# Error retrieving information from server [DF-CHARTA-01}

Tags: google-play-store, system-error

I am getting this message when trying to get onto Google Play store. What does this mean and how can I correct this?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a G Suite (formerly known as Google Apps for Work and Google Apps for Education) account?

Comment: You can watch this video and most probably is your fix. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCxt_DnmOQo

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this error is related to G Suite (formerly known as Google Apps).  Your account administrator most likely disabled Play Store recently.  If you are not an admin and cannot ask the admins to re-enable Play Store, your only option is to add a personal Google account to your phone, and switch to that account in the Play Store as described [here](http://android-fix.com/google-play-problems/27-df-charta-01.html).

> To get rid of the error [DF-CHARTA-01] one can always add a new
>   account to his Android-phone, then go to Google Play menu and switch
>   Google Play to use the latter. To do so one has to follow the steps:
>
> 1. Open Google Play;
> 2. Tap Settings;
> 3. You will see the name and email address associated with the account you are using;
> 4. To select a different account, scroll down Selector;
> 5. Select the account you want to use and tap on it.

Answer (score 0):

I bought two Samsung Galaxy Sky phones for my twin sons' birthday gifts and they said they could not connect to Google Play store. The message after touching the icon was:

> error retrieving information from server [DF-CHARTA-01]

This is how I fixed it:

I had created for each son a Gmail account, but I realized today that when they played with their phones last night they each also added their school Gmail account, which then became default email associated with Play Store. So,

1. I went to Google play and tapped the 3 horizontal lines in the Search box next to words "Google Play" .
2. Then just looked at top of bar and saw his school account (*which was our last name @ our school board address*).
   I touched that, then saw the gmail account name that I created for them show up underneath, and touched that and that finally worked.

Keep in mind **to not use a school associated Gmail account.**